# How to show Django admin's template style after deploy to Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, static, admin

After I deployed to Heroku,the css style were broken.

I have set DEBUG = FALSE in settings.py file.

I have searched for some information.They told me that put Django's static files to AWS S3. But what I can't understand is that aren't Django's admin template style(css or js) in it's soft package?
Why they can't been found after deployed to Heroku?

My application's front-end is using public CDN, I don't want to solve the problem about admin template to use AWS S3.
Is there any right way to do it?

Comment: Did you read Heroku's documentation on [serving static assets in Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you.I didn't read the article clearly.The important thing is that I didn't run `python manage.py collectstatic`.